# ¿Cómo graficar puntos maximos de ondas en Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Estoy intentando graficar únicamente los puntos máximos (amplitud máxima) de varias ondas sinusoidales que se generan con la misma fase, para lo cual utilicé `append` para almacenar los datos de estos puntos, sin embargo, se grafican valores para el rango de la amplitud de la primera onda hasta la última, y la fase donde ocurre cada amplitud máxima no se respeta y se grafica para todos los valores de z (utilicé el plano z-x).
Por ejemplo, para tres ondas, espero obtener lo siguiente:

[image: Amplitudes maximas de las ondas]

Sin embargo, con mi código obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from numpy import cos, sin
#constants
pi = 3.14159
f=2 #frequency
A=1 #Amplitude

#Range to evaluate z in pha
z = np.linspace(0.0, 3.00,80)

x1=[]
z1=[]

#Creating the waves:
#range of j define the number of waves are plotting
for j in range(1,4,1):
  #general phase:
  pha=2*pi*f*z
  #general wave equation:
  x=A*cos(pha)+j
  #plot of the sinusoidal waves:
  plt.plot(z,x,'blue')
  #Saving the values of each amplitude:
  #Max value when cos(pha)=1 --> x=A+j
  if (x == A+j).any():
    xx=np.amax(x)
    x1.append(xx)
    z1.append(z)
    #Plotting the dots for each wave:
    plt.plot(z1,x1,'red')

plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: bueno, basicamente deberías usar: plt.plot(z1,x1,'o',color='red') ya que así verás los puntos, pero hay otro problema y es que z1 contiene más puntos de los que debería y para ser honesto no conozco la fórmula para aislar solo los necesarios, pero ya tenés una idea general.

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto la solución:

Edición:

Aquí está la respuesta:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import argrelmax

# Función para graficar ondas sinusoidales con la misma fase y puntos rojos en cada amplitud máxima de cada onda:
def graficar_ondas_sinusoidales(num_ondas):
    # Constantes
    pi = 3.14159
    f = 2  # Frecuencia
    A = 1  # Amplitud

    # Rango para evaluar z en pha
    z = np.linspace(0.0, 3.0 / 2, 80)

    # Creando las ondas:
    # Rango de j define el número de ondas que se están graficando
    for j in range(1, num_ondas + 1):
        # Fórmula general de la onda sinusoidal:
        x = A * cos(2 * pi * f * z) + j

        # Graficando la onda sinusoidal:
        plt.plot(z, x, color='blue')

        # Encontrando los índices de las amplitudes máximas en el array x:
        indices = argrelmax(x)

        # Graficando un punto rojo en la ubicación de cada amplitud máxima de cada frecuencia de la onda:
        plt.scatter(z[indices], A * cos(2 * pi * f * z[indices]) + j, color='red')

    plt.grid()
    plt.show()

graficar_ondas_sinusoidales(4)
```

[image]

Comment: Puedes mejorar tu respuesta si explicas qué cambiaste y por qué.